# Why does PHP return empty string when using ternary operator?

Tags: php

I have folowing string:

```
$html .= '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="' . trim($alt) ? $alt : $this->escape($name) . '" />';
```

Which looks ok from first glance but it will append empty string to `$html` which took some head scratching..

But if I add parenthesis around ternary operator it returns expected result

```
$html .= '<img src="' . $url . '" alt="' . (trim($alt) ? $alt : $this->escape($name)) . '" />';
```

My question how does parser parse this expresion that it's possible to get nothing appended to the result?

Comment: If it cuts off as `'<img src="' . $url . '" alt="'` then you won't see it in the browser unless you view source because its not valid html.

Comment: @developerwjk I had this code inside anchor tag and it generated empty anchor when checked source which seemed weird

Comment: @developerwjk main question is how does php parse this kind of expression, shouldn't it first check for ternary operation and only then join strings

Comment: I'm surprised PHP wouldn't just fail and give you a blank screen (or stop outputting altogether at this point) because I think Java would fail to compile if you tried this and left the parenthesis off.